# react-redux) mapStateToProps works, but sending local(?) props to child component returns undefined.

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hi I have some issue with passing props to child component.
Problem is, sending global state as props to child component works correctly, but I can't send local props to child component.

I don't know why but it returns undefined.

```
    const mapStateToProps =(state)=>{
    return state.itemInfo
}

export class ItemInformationContainer extends React.Component{
    componentWillUnmount(){
        store.dispatch(hideItemInfo());
    }
    handleBackToList = (e)=>{
        console.log('back please');
        store.dispatch(hideItemInfo());
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <WrappedItemComponent backToList={this.handleBackToList} {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}

export const ItemInformation =(props)=>{
    console.log(props);
    return(/*some codes*/
    )
}
const WrappedItemComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemInformation);
```

in ItemInformation component, I used console.log(props) to check if presentational component is getting backToList props from parent component.

but result is

{backToList: undefined, content: {…}, type: "country", status: "show", dispatch: ƒ}
backToList: undefined

backToList is undefined.

I really need this props. How do I fix it?

please ignore componentWillUnmount. If handleBackToList will work correctly, that lifecycle method will be removed from code.

Comment: It's working fine! https://codesandbox.io/s/31893rzno1

Comment: @HardikModha that's strange. I get undefined in my code.. and in your code, I see you are doing alert in backToList. but, I  cannot see any alert

Comment: I have not called this function yet! :) Update: Now it will show an alert!

Comment: See if there are any errors in the code. Try running jshint.

Comment: @kustkust Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem then. I would expect that your actual code differs from what you posted.

Comment: @HardikModha thank you I found error in my code and solved the issue.

Comment: @estus thanks. you know, the reason was.. really stupid reason.. I was stupid..

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was my silly and stupid mistake.

The error was caused because the grandparent component passed the same props to parent component.

So the structure of code is so:

Countries component -> ItemInformationContainer component -> ItemInformation component

I was stupid and did such things in Countries component

```
return(
      <section id="ItemResult">
            <ItemInformationContainer backToList={this.backToList} content={this.state.content}/>
                    </section>
      )
```

passed backToList props to child component and there weren't backToList function in Countries component 
of course backToList is undefined and ItemInformationContainer also gets undefined as I understood.

So, I just removed backToList props in Countries component and works fine.

Comment: `propTypes` to the rescue ;) - `{...this.props}` overwritten the earlier one